# jest --changesSince runs coverage on unchanged reference files

Tags: react-native, jestjs, code-coverage

**Example:**

I import code from `anotherFile.js` into both `myFile.js` and `myFile.test.js` to assert that the imported code was called correctly.

When I run jest with `--changesSince` and `--coverage` it thinks `anotherFile.js` was a changed file (via reference I think) and also runs a coverage on that.

Problem is that the coverage for `anotherFile.js` now falls below the coverage threshold even though `anotherFile.js` has its own test file and coverage above the coverage threshold.

My understanding is that `anotherFile.test.js` never runs and that the coverage is done solely on `myFile.test.js`

**Expected:**

To either not run coverage on referenced unchanged files or to at least run the test file for the unchanged reference files.

**Questions:**

- Is it expected behaviour to run coverage on unchanged referenced/imported
  files?
- If yes then how can one avoid the coverage threshold failing?

Hopefully this explains the issue. If any additional information is needed let me know.